buidling NIfTI C library in Windows: undefined references?
I'm building the NIfTI C libraries on Windows using MinGW gcc 14.2.0 and CMake 3.30.3. I have noticed two things:
1: I had previously compiled the Z library, libz.dll.a with the same build tools, and although the path to the library was found automatically and I had set the include directory that holds zlib.h, compilation of the "znz" library required to open both .nii and .nii.gz files fails. I can make that work by also adding the directory to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS variable (and just to make sure, also to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS). 
2:  Now I can compile the static libararies, including the executables etc., but when I check the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag to build DLLs, after successfully building libznz.dll, libnifticdf.dl, libniftiio.dll, second_test.exe, nifti_stats.exe, nifti1_test.exe building first_test.exe fails with the errors: 
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c (.text.startup+0x27c): undefined reference to `nifti_intent_code'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x2f8): undefined reference to `nifti_stat2hzscore'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x34f): undefined reference to `nifti_stat2cdf'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x40a): undefined reference to `nifti_stat2rcdf'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x45a): undefined reference to `nifti_cdf2stat'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x508): undefined reference to `nifti_stat2zscore'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x5e7): undefined reference to `nifti_stat2cdf'
ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nifti_stats.dir/objects.a(nifti_stats.c.obj):nifti_stats.c:(.text.startup+0x607): undefined reference to `nifti_stat2cdf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Does anyone understand

why building the NIfTI libraries as DLL results in this linking error for only 1 of the programs?
why compilation of the ZNZ libraries does not use the directory information from CMakeLists.txt?


Add -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF to your cmake command line to skip building those tests when building with -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON

Thanks for your response! When I use ..\..\opt\cmake-3.30.3\bin\cmake.exe -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=D:\usr\local\opt\mingw-gcc-14.2.0\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:\usr\local\opt\mingw-gcc-14.2.0\bin\g++.exe -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:/usr/local/opt/mingw-gcc-14.2.0/bin/mingw32-make.exe -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-ID:\usr\local\include and then run make, unfortunately I still get the error. It is strange that the libraries and the other executables build corectly?

What I have done now seems to work (although I'm no expert in CMake): in Testing\niftilibCMakeLists.txt it said ADD_EXECUTABLE(first_test nifti_test.c);  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(first_test niftiio) (semicolon added by me). After changing the second part to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(first_test niftiio nifticdf) I could compile.
